# How to determine if one SQL statement generates a dataset that is a subset/superset of other SQL statement?

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark

I want to write a system to materialize partial datasets that are repeated across the workload of a warehouse, so an expensive and common computation is computed only once, and all subsequent queries using that dataset (or a subset of that dataset) do a plain SELECT from the materialized dataset instead of running the query again. The warehouse is using Spark + HDFS.

Finding the most common queries, subqueries and CTEs was easy and already solved.
What I'm stuck now is to find a way to find materialization candidates, I can't device a method to identify if one query is a superset of another (or, conversely, one query being a subset of another). If I knew that, then it would be possible to do query rewriting and replace the expensive subquery by the already materialized table.

One way I was thinking about this is to build a graph where queries and sub-queries are nodes and the edges represent the fact that one query is answered by the other. But I'm having a hard time building the edges of this graph.

In summary: Given 2 SQL statements, for example, given 2 queries:

Q1: `SELECT col1, col2 FROM table;`

and

Q2: `SELECT col1 FROM table WHERE col2 > 0;`

How can I determine Q2 is a subset of Q1?

This is a simple example, joins, aggregations, unions, where and having conditions also must be taken into consideration. 
Evaluating datasets it is not an option, should be determined just based on the SQL statement and/or the execution plans (we are talking about multi petabytes datasets and comparing datasets is too resource intensive)

My ideas so far: take the list of projections and compare, of the list of projected columns of Q1 contains the list of projections of Q2 then Q1 might be a superset of Q2. 
Also check the columns involved in the filters and what filters are being applied.

Comment: I don't understand what YOU mean by subset.  The first query returns two columns; the second only returns 1.  Each element is therefore necessarily different and the sets are not comparable.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, subset as in one query could be answered by the other.
In my example, given that Q2 is a subset of Q1, one could rewrite Q2 like this

```SELECT col1 FROM (SELECT col1, col2 FROM table) WHERE col2 > 0;```